# How to un-mirror the camera in Slack?

Tags: camera, slack

When checking my camera settings in Slack, I noticed that it was mirroring the camera. Is there any way to get it to show the un-mirrored image instead?

Other similar applications (e.g., Webex, Microsoft Teams) have such a setting, but I can't seem to find it in Slack.

Is this something like what Microsoft Teams has where I have to actually be in a meeting (or a huddle) to find that setting?

Comment: Check if it's mirrored for everyone or just for you. Probably the latter.